# I got a problem with lef hand Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Tags: javascript

[image: Code]

I'm trying to write a program to count the average of 5 numbers that are entered into input fields, but it's not working as expected, what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not a "give me code plz" site - you need to show what you have tried. A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is required so that we can see what *has* been done so that anyone interested in answering your question can actually have a starting point. If you [write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), the chances of a good answer increase by a lot. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: You are trying to assign result to an element. Are you trying to assign it to that element’s innerHTML?

Comment: Please post your code as text, not a link to a painting of it.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById` returns element object which has multiple properties.

If you want to get value of input field, after selected input field you can access it's value using `value` property, e.g.

```js
var num1 = document.getElementById('n1').value;
//                                      ^^^^^^
```

Now your num1 variable contains the text entered into input field.
Notice that I said text, not number. If you want to apply math to the values, you need to convert them to numbers, like this:

```js
var num1 = Number(document.getElementById('n1').value);
//         ^^^^^^^                                   ^
```

Only then you will get correct result. But we're not done yet, as you probably want to see that result. As I mentioned previously, `document.getElementById` gives you reference to the element, that has multiple properties. Another property is `innerText`. You can set it to the value you want to be able to see it:

```js
document.getElementById('everresult').innerText = result;
```